# Java FileNotFound error even though files exists and is in same directory? how do i resolve?

Tags: java

I'm trying to read some numbers from a text file in java to defines some shapes and display them in the GUI window, however every time I try to run the code and import the values in the text file it throws a FileNotFoundException even though the file is in the same directory and exists and opens fine.

Code inserted below and file structure for the project.

Any ideas on how to solve this please? Much appreciated in advance.

I have checked the file actually exists which it does and if the file opens and shows the data which it also does and that the file isn't corrupt which it isn't.

```
public static void addShapes(){
    BounceBox box = new BounceBox(700,500);        
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("ex3.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);

    box.start();
}
```

[image]

Comment: you know that it's in the same folder but java doesn't know it. You have to put your code in a try/catch to show that you're prepared to handle if something goes wrong.

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder Yes exactly. And ex3.txt is in the same folder as the class file and yes the class file is in the package. Still same issue.

Comment: @NikosTzianas hey may choose to throw it, although not good practice.

Comment: Does surrounding it in try/catch work? If that's the case then Madhu Bhat answered the question correctly.

Comment: Also try putting the path of the file starting from the package the package or ignoring the package. So if it is in a package com.bif and in folder rsc then try "com/bif/rsc/ex3.txt" or simply "rsc/ex3.txt" (sorry for the spam)

Comment: @JustAFellowCoderwill try that now, and no prolem thank you for the spam :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see the error, it says

> Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

This means that it's not a runtime exception with the file not being found, but it's a compile time exception. It's due to the below line:

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("ex3.txt");
```

It means that there is a possibility of `FileNotFoundException` at that line, and that it should either be added to the method signature as below:

```
public static void addShapes() throws FileNotFoundException {
        BounceBox box = new BounceBox(700,500);

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("ex3.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);

        box.start();
    }
```

or the line should be surrounded with a `try-catch` block, catching the `FileNotFoundException` as below:

```
public static void addShapes(){
    BounceBox box = new BounceBox(700,500);
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = null;
        fileIn = new FileInputStream("ex3.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    box.start();
}
```

Comment: Tried both but still same issue. Any other ideas ?

Comment: If you have tried both, @MahmoudYassine, then the error that you are getting would not be the same. Can you please confirm if you're getting a different error after adding my suggestion?

Comment: Just ran the code with your second edit and the error is as follows:               run:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ex3.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
 at bounceboxapp.Main.addShapes(Main.java:131)
 at bounceboxapp.Main.main(Main.java:37)

Comment: @MahmoudYassine yes now the file is not being found, if you see it's a different error from before.

Comment: Just ran the code again and put in the full path to file and has worked!!! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome, @MahmoudYassine. Do look at the various ways you can provide file path on the web. And please accept my answer if you feel it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void addShapes() {
    BounceBox box = new BounceBox(700,500);
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("ex3.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    box.start();
}
```

Comment: Just an advice, @JuanRomo, you need to add explanation with an answer, since just by looking at a piece of code, the OP might not understand the reasoning behind the answer. Adding an explanation helps. And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a "Unreported Exception" which means your code can throw an exception(which is FileNotFound Exception) and you are not catching it. So surround your code with try-catch.

```
 FileInputStream fileIn = null;

    try {
        fileIn = new FileInputStream("ex3.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // catch your exception here.
    }

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today, which took me about two hours to partially figured it out. It was so annoying. Depending on how your class code is structured, Java does not allow you to read text file within the method definition. Try reading it in the main method, then take that object (FileInputStream) as input to your addShapes() method. 
Let me know if it works :)